# Get modules names from a package in python

Tags: python, python-2.6

Lets say that I have a python package and I want to list out all the modules within this package. i.e.

```
>>> import my_package
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getmembers(my_package, inspect.ismodule)
>>> []
```

For some reason I am getting an empty list. Now if I manually load a module from the package then:

```
>>> import my_package.module_a
>>> inspect.getmembers(my_package, inspect.ismodule)
>>> ['module_a, <module '....'>]
```

Assuming that I have multiple modules and I don't want to load them one by one is there any other way to do it? (p.s. `from my_package import *` won't work).

Furthermore do you know what is causing this behavior? Is anything that has to do with namespaces?

P.S Packages are not locally installed, I am loading everything from a server.

Comment: What happens if you access `my_package.module_a` *before* the second import?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a guaranteed way to get every possible module that could ever exist within a package namespace.  You can search the package directory for subpackage directories and module files, but there's nothing stopping some bit of code from just creating a `types.ModuleType` object and attaching it the top package.  If the package you're dealing with is a namespace package, there could be any number of modules and subpackages located in different locations on disk.